# Command in a MenuItem parent not executing when having MenuItem childs

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code structure in a C# WPF program:

```
                    <MenuItem Header="father" 
                              Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, 
                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                                   Converter ={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}"
                              Command="{Binding SetFatherCommand}">

                        <MenuItem Header="son1"
                                  Command="{Binding SetSon1Command}"
                                  CommandParameter="{x:Static Types:CableType.Phase1}"
                                  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}"/>
                    </MenuItem>
```

When I click on the MenuItem father the command SetFatherCommand is not executed but if I comment the lines corresponding to the MenuItem son1 the command from the MenuItem father will be executed.

I am a bit lost, I think the command binding in the child is somehow affecting the command binding in the father but I don´t understand why and how can I solve it. I will appreciate any input.

Comment: What is your logic for CanExecute() for Father command?

Comment: It checks whether a field is true or false and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Command` property does not work on `MenuItem`'s which have sub `MenuItem`'s